# Getting the Helper function to compile

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to get this list to parse through a knowledge base, but I am having trouble getting the helper function to work.

The program I am trying to create, outputs a list of quests from a knowledge base which comes from at least 2 quest types, and has to have a total experience value below a cutoff.
format of allquest is:
allquest(Questtext,QuestType,ExpvalueofQuest).

```
allquest(water for village,Main quest, 2000). 
allquest(get book for elder,fetch quest,1000). 
allquest(kill 20 birds, bounty quest, 1000). 

questCheck([], [_], Tot) :- Tot >= CUTOFF.
questCheck([H|T], [ListOfTypes], Tot) :- allQuests(H, Type, Exp), T2 is Tot + Exp, 
questCheck(T, [Type|ListOfTypes], T2).

questCheckH([H|T]) :- allQuests(H, Type, Exp), questCheck(H, [Type], Exp).
```

Overall the logic of the ruleset is that it takes in a list as a parameter, iterates through that list keeping track of the exp total of each quest, Once the list has been completely iterated through it checks the total against some numbers to make sure it's 'Ok.', then it returns.

However if I input an uninstanctiated list [A], it should return list combination that fulfill my requirements.

the code should work like this if CUTOFF = 3000

```
?-questCheckH([A]).

water for village,get book for elder
;water for village, kill 20 birds
;get book for elder, water for village
;get book for elder, kill 20 birds, water for village
;kill 20 birds, water for village
;kill 20 birds, get book for elder, water for village
```

I know I need to work a T into the questCheckH with an additional predicate but am not sure how to word the predicate I need.

Comment: what is "Expvalue"? is it "Experience_Value"? "... and has to have a total experience value" -- who? who has to have it? "also I plan..." no also's please, ask each thing in its own question.

Comment: what is your sample query? what is its intended output? write it down, even if you don't yet have all the predicates defined (but explain purpose of each predicate that you are using).

Comment: beware that on SO there's a question ban if you ask questions that aren't "well received". You need to make your questions work, or you'll risk a ban from the system. Deleting them is not an option - it counts as bad behaviour, towards the ban. And welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Comment: edited for rules

Comment: "Overall the logic of the ruleset is that it takes in a list as a parameter" the ruleset does not take anything, it just is. Explain what it is. Show a concrete example. "takes in a list as a parameter" what list? what that list is? "iterates through that list" don't tell us what it "does", tell us what you want to get back from it. as in "`my_length(ground_list, its_length)` take in a fully defined list `ground_list`, finds out its length and sets `its_length` to hold that length as a value; `its_length` is expected to be an uninstantiated variable before the call to `my_length`". if that is_

Comment: if some words in that sentence are unclear to you, you really need to read tutorials first. You can't ask C questions without understanding what is *variable*, *function*, *block*, in C.